# XRDP client crashing on loading screen for Jetson Nano

Tags: nvidia, crash, remote-desktop, xrdp

I am trying to access my Jetson nano from an XRDP client (mac). I have installed XRDP on the jetson using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

It seems to work, as when I type

```
systemctl status xrdp
```

I get the following output:

```
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-16 10:08:07 EDT; 7min ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 5046 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SU
  Process: 4996 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, sta
 Main PID: 5160 (xrdp)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4174)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           └─5160 /usr/sbin/xrdp
```

However, after attempting to connect from the client, I see the NVIDIA boot screen for a second and then the client crashes. How can I prevent this from happening?

Note: I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the image that NVIDIA provided

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem came with the upgrade from `libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1_arm64` to `libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1_arm64`.

Unfortunately it also still persists with `libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.101-2~18.04.1_arm64`. Not 100% sure for `libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.102-1ubuntu1_arm64` as this also requires to ignore the dependency to a newer `libc6`.

But if you're on `libdrm2=2.4.101-2~18.04.1` and manually install just the `libdrm-amdgpu1=2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1` it still works.

I could not find out why this occurs exactly. Especially wondering because the nano definitely has no AMD GPU... . And my hope that it gets solved after a year is fading too. And it's no permanent workaround because of the soon not fulfillable dependencies. Probably someone is able to dig deeper into it with this information.

Comment: I'm on libdrm2=2.4.101-2~18.04.1, but when I run `sudo apt install libdrm-amdgpu1=2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1` I got "Version '2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' for 'libdrm-amdgpu1' was not found"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue with the Jetson Nano, and the solution is not obvious but very simple - it will do this if you're logged in on the console of the Jetson when you try to RDP. Logging off / rebooting and then connecting via RDP fixes it.

Just verified on a fresh install:

- Image SD Card, insert into Jetson and boot
- Run through Ubuntu first-run setup
- After reboot, run `apt-get install -y xrdp`
- Reboot / Log off
- Connect via RDP

Comment: This didn't fix it for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The log (`/etc/log/xrdp.log`) on the jetson showed access problems to `/etc/xrdp/cert.pem` (which links to `/etc/ssl/private/`..).

xrdp only accepts users in the group ssl-cert.  Add the user to the group.

```
sudo adduser myUserName ssl-cert
```

However - note that the rdp session opens a new "X11" session (not as in Windows where it "take" the desktop) which can be a bit tricky to configure (choosing X11rdp defaults to a twm session - configured in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today. It turns out it was caused by gnome (more specifically, the MESA GL library).
Didn’t want to waste more time on this. So I installed xfce4 and used it instead. That solved the problem.

Here are the steps:

1. Install xfce4 with

   ```
    sudo apt install xfce4
   ```
2. Comment out the last two lines in "/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh"
3. Give permission to file with

   ```
    sudo chmod 777 /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
   ```
4. Add the following line to this file "/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh" in the end

   ```
    startxfce4
   ```
5. Restart xrdp with

   ```
    sudo service xrdp restart
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, there was a syntax error on ~/.xrdprc (while setting the favorite apps)

I could see this error in ~/.xrdp-error

I fixed that by commenting out those 10 lines, but I'm sure there's a cleaner solution.